# Unexpected Thread was aborted errors

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker, background-process

I've inherited an old asp vb .net website. This website has an import process where the user uploads a file, then the file contents are processed, then imported into the database. This import is being done in a separate thread that is started as soon as the user clicks a 'process document' button. This thread is being started via the code below:

```
Dim thread As System.Threading.Thread = New Thread(AddressOf Importer.ImportDocument)
thread.Start(Document.Id)
```

Usually the import starts, loads everything it needs from the file, runs the import, then gets to a giant save method that saves a lot within a transaction.
The problem I'm having is that often with large imports it takes a while to load the file, then process the file, then save the results and often the import will just fail with the exception message 'Thread was being aborted'.
When testing from visual studio it'll often just kill the entire website without even catching an error to log.

The only thing I could think of was the method in which the thread was being started. So I tried using HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem to start the background thread instead, but it still has the same issue.

Any advice on where to look next would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to debug whatever you can. Start with a breakpoint inside `Importer.ImportDocument`, then any sub procedure calls inside that.

Comment: You definitely shouldn't be creating new threads in an ASP.NET app. HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem is an improvement, though really this sort of problem is best approached by processing the long running job in an entirely separate process, and then using a messaging service (like RabbitMQ, Azure Service Bus, or AWS SQS/SNS) to communicate from the site to the separate process. That keeps them independently scalable, and allows the site to focus on doing what web apps are intended for: processing HTTP requests. If QueueBackgroundWorkItem isn't working, then create a [mcve].

Comment: Attach a system debugger to the process. VS debuggers work with source code. System debuggers work with processes. Here is an introduction https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/12/brief-introduction-to-windows-debugger.html. But you need to read help for the thread switching command. Older versions are here. They will work  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363.